# Symfony / Doctrine - OneToMany too many queries

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

is there a way to lower lower one to many queries?

I have self-referenced one to many entity(category tree). I'm trying to get all children like this:

```
private function getChildren(string $category): array
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine();
    $category = $em->getRepository(Category::class)->getByUrl($category);
    $children = $category->getChildren();
    $childrenArr = [];
    if (!empty($children)) {
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $childrenArr[] = $child->getId();
            if (!empty($child->getChildren())) {
                $this->getChildren($child->getUrl(), $childrenArr);
            }
        }
    }
    return $childrenArr;
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
public function getByUrl(string $url)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    $qb->where('c.url = :url');
    $qb->setParameter('url', $url);
    return $qb->getQuery()->useQueryCache(true)->getSingleResult();
}
```

Problem is, if it finds 5 children, it creates 57 queries... It's ridiculous.

UPDATE:

Entity structure:

```
/**
     * One Category has Many Subcategories.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER"))
     */
    private $children;
    /**
     * Many Subcategories have One Category.
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $parent;



  /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $child
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addChild(\App\Entity\Product\Category $child): Category
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\App\Entity\Product\Category $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren(): Collection
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Category $parent
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function setParent(\App\Entity\Product\Category $parent = null): Category
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \App\Entity\Product\Category
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add products
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Product $products
     *
     * @return Category
     */
    public function addProducts(\App\Entity\Product\Product $products)
    {
        $this->products[] = $products;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove products
     *
     * @param \App\Entity\Product\Product $products
     */
    public function removeProducts(\App\Entity\Product\Product $products)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($products);
    }

    /**
     * Get products
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }
```

Used fetch=EAGER it removed 2 queries(was 57 now its 55)

Comment: how are your entities structured? And since you are already using the query builder, why not use it to create a query to grab the 5 children.

Comment: @Confidence hi, I've updated my question. I don't know how many children it has, it can have 0 or 5 or 10 so I can't just create query. Or I misunderstood you? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To avoid too many queries when I request all children, I do a fetch="EAGER" on my entity, it will automatically do a innerJoin from children table.

Ex:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CoreBundle\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $children;
```

Comment: Thanks, used this, now it's 55 queries instead of 57